# Calculating date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am having problem calculating the number of years a faculty member has been hired. (current time - faculty hire date)

I am trying to use this, however i keep getting error that DATEDIFF is an invalid identifier. Please help.

```
SELECT FAC_FN , DATEDIFF ('CURDATE()' , 'FAC_HIRE DATE')
FROM FACULTY;

--CREATING TABLE FACULTY

CREATE TABLE FACULTY
(
FAC_ID NUMBER (4) CONSTRAINT FAC_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
FAC_FN VARCHAR2 (15),
FAC_LN VARCHAR2 (15),
FAC_DEPT VARCHAR2 (10),
FAC_RANK VARCHAR2 (10),
FAC_HIRE_DATE DATE,
FAC_SALARY NUMBER (7),
FAC_SUPERVISOR NUMBER (4)
);

--INSERTING RECORDS INTO FACULTY TABLE

INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES ( 9001 , 'Leonard' , 'Vince' , 'IS' , 'ASST' , TO_DATE('12-APR-1997','DD-MON-YYYY') , 67000 , 9003);

INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES ( 9002 , 'Victor' , 'Strong' , 'CSCI' , 'ASSO' , TO_DATE('8-AUG-1999','DD-MM-YYYY') , 70000 , 9003);

INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES ( 9003 , 'Nicki' , 'Colan' , 'IS' , 'PROF' , TO_DATE('20-AUG-1981','DD-MM-YYYY') , 75000, 9010);

INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES ( 9004 , 'Fred' , 'Wells' , 'ACCT' , 'ASST' , TO_DATE('28-AUG-1996','DD-MM-YYYY'), 60000, 9010);

INSERT INTO FACULTY VALUES ( 9010 , 'Chris' , 'Macon' , 'ACCT' , 'ASST' , TO_DATE('4-AUG-1980','DD-MM-YYYY') , 75000 , '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes (they are causing MySQL to parse the function arguments as string literals):

```
SELECT FAC_FN, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FAC_HIRE_DATE) FROM FACULTY
```

Note also that [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns a result in *number of days*; to obtain the difference in years, you may wish to use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) instead.